# Checking for equality in two lists using == operator

Tags: c++, list, testing, equality

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm working on a method that will check whether two lists are identical using the == operator.  Here's my code as it is right now.

```
bool List::operator==(const List& original) const {
if(this != &original){
    if( mySize != original.getSize() ) { return false; }

    unsigned counter = 0;
    Node * nPtr = original.myFirst;
    Node * myPtr = myFirst;
    while (counter < mySize ) {
        if( this->myFirst == nPtr ) {
            if (counter == 0){
                counter++;
                nPtr = nPtr->myNext;
            }
            if (myFirst->myNext == nPtr) {
                counter ++;
                nPtr = nPtr->myNext;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true; }
```

So, from what I understand, here's what my code is doing.  It checks whether their addresses are the same and, if it is, it returns true.  Otherwise, it checks to see that their sizes are identical.  If not, returns false.  If true, goes through the list and checks the different values starting at the first address and going through until it reaches the last one.

However, it's failing this test I wrote and I'm not sure why or how:

```
List list3;
list3.append(33);
List list4;
list4.append(33);       // [33]
assert( list4 == list3 );
assert( list3 == list4 );
cout << " 3 " << flush;
```

My append method adds a certain value to the list and I've tested it.  That method works fine.

I realize this question may be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062652/testing-if-a-linked-list-is-equal-to-each-other) question already asked but that didn't really help me much. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Where is it in the question where you're actually asking a _question?_ In other words, what is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: You're comparing the actual node pointers, not their "values" or whatever other data they contain. The pointers will never be the same since the one node can't be in two different lists at the same time.

Comment: Where do you increment `myPtr` (the pointer to the member head of the list)?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing with the `counter` variable in those if statements; it looks wrong.

Comment: @paxdiablo, the problem I am having is that my code won't pass the test and I don't know why.